# HFSQL connect to initial catalog

Tags: windev

I have already running a project in production.
And .wdd is missing. I can't use server/client, for it.
Can I create .wdd file? Or connect to catalog without it?
I using pypyodbc and python3 for it

Answer (score 0):

Only way to find wdd file is in the WinDev project directory. 
But also if you don't have the project, you could connect to DB via ODBC using ODBC driver for HFSQL. With that you only have to connect to ODBC and the HFSQL driver do the rest.

https://help.windev.com/en-US/?3044179

Comment: I can connect to HFSQL by host and port...
But I need to pull data within a running server...
And I was read ODBC doc - for connection to db folder - I need ,wdd file.

Do you have I can connect to db folder?

Comment: So do you have access to physical files? you could build a new project to generate a new Analysis file (wdd), Importing files to the project.

Comment: Or you can dynamically get the structure of the files. https://doc.windev.com/en-US/?20064 and create empty files, import them in a new project and generate a new wdd file